# How to query the last N Parent rows with that had the most recent children created? in ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, mssql-jdbc

I have 2 models, `Device` and `HealthRecord` with the basic relationship of:
`device has_many health_records`
`health_records belong_to device`.

I want to get the **LAST 10 devices** that has the most recently created health_records.
I can get it using this, but this gets ALL of the records:

```
Device
  .select("devices.id, MAX(health_records.id) AS latest_health_id")
  .joins(:health_records)
  .group("devices.id")
  .order("latest_health_id DESC")
```

If I add `.limit(10)`, it just gives me a `Device::ActiveRecord_Relation` which i cannot inspect. (when i inspect it says Invalid column name 'latest_health_id'.). Adding `.first(10)` does not work too.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description shared below mentioned query will fetch devices of last 10 created health records.

```
Device
  .select("devices.id")
  .joins(:health_records)
  .group("devices.id")
  .order("health_records.created_at DESC").limit(10)
```

Comment: I can get the result I want by doing this in console: `HealthRecord.last(N).map(&:device_id).uniq` where i change N until i get size of 10.
The query you gave me did not match the result unfortunately. Not sure If I am correct though.

Comment: I queried `HealthRecord.last.device_id`, and the result is not included in the result of your query. :( Maybe I worded my question wrong, thanks for your help.

Comment: The query which I shared will give the ids of devices corresponding to the health records (based on the number of records for created for that device id) and max result will be 10 and min can be the number of records in the join table.

Comment: Did you inspect the result of the query using as_json?

Comment: Yes when I enter your query it gives me list of the device ids already. I thought that it is incorrect because when I query `HealthRecord.last.device_id`, it is not included in the result of your query, which I think it should since it looks at the last health_record.

Comment: I used your `as_json` in the answer i posted, thank you. i didnt know that can be used here until now :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your goal with the following query:

```
Device
  .joins(:health_records)
  .order('health_records.created_at DESC')
  .group(:id)
  .distinct
  .limit(10)
```

This will return `Device::ActiveRecord_Relation` object. If you want only ids, just add `pluck(:id)` at the end, which will change your query from `SELECT  DISTINCT "devices".*` to `SELECT  DISTINCT "devices"."id"` and return `Array` of ids.

Comment: I entered `Device.joins(:health_records).order('health_records.created_at DESC').group(:id).distinct.limit(10).pluck(:id)` in the console and got an error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Invalid column name 'created_at'.`.
I updated my answer to the question, inspired by your answer. thanks

Comment: I don't know the exact structure of your database, but you can use any column to find the newest `health_records`. I assumed it would be `created_at` but it seems you just use `id`, which would still work in my query. Additionaly, this solution does no additional ruby operations like `map` or `uniq`, it just generates and executes sql query, which should be much faster.

Comment: Im using jruby on rails 4.2.10, with the `jdbcmssql` adapter. The device and health_record connection is standard one. Dont know why I'm getting error when I try it, maybe its the adapter, or the jruby

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that should probably work for you (albeit untested):

```
Device.where(id: HealthRecord.select(:device_id)
                   .group(:device_id)
                   .order("MAX(health_records.id) DESC")
                   .limit(10)
)
```

This should result in a query similar to

```
SELECT 
  devices.*
FROM 
  devices
WHERE 
  id IN (
     SELECT 
       health_records.device_id
     FROM 
       health_records 
     GROUP BY 
       health_records.device_id 
     ORDER BY 
       MAX(health_records.id) DESC
     LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I ended up using either of this two:

```
Device
  .select("devices.id, MAX(health_records.id) AS latest_health_id")
  .joins(:health_records)
  .group("devices.id")
  .order("latest_health_id DESC")
  .map(&:id).first(10)

Device
  .joins(:health_records)
  .order('health_records.created_at DESC')
  .pluck(:id).uniq.first(10)
```

it gives me an array of the last 10 device ids that most recently created a health_record